# Root a D-Link 1550-4 NAS

Tags: root, nas

`su -` returns `su: must be suid to work properly` and then `sudo` returns `sudo: must be setuid root`

This is on a D-Link 1550-4 NAS, running what I believe to be a modified version of SLAX Linux. I got the thing for free (bricked/would not boot) so then I Googled and followed [this](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/network-storage-and-backup/nas/dns-series/dns-1550-04/uk_dns_1550_04_how_to_recover_via_a_usb_flash_drive) guide. Initially I was able to log in as root and I was able to even change my passwords, setup users, etc. but as soon as I got to the web management GUI to update to the correct and most recent firmware it flashes everything back to default settings with a locked root user. Right now the only account I have access to is the default account "administrator" with a password of "password" (the default settings). I'd like to simply change some passwords and poke around a little (since I got the thing for free). Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: Depends on the mechanism used to flash but you might copy the `sudo` executable to persistent storage so they aren't lost this next time.

Comment: chmod +s /usr/bin/sudo and 
chmod +s /bin/su

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini That would require having root access in the first place.

Comment: You can't gain root access if the system is configured not to let you in. That's rather the point. If the default system image doesn't give the user root access, you may need to install a different one. In other words, you need to jailbreak (“root”) the device.